# Bootstrap Glyphicons gives 'Invalid property value' on CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've just tried to use a glyphicon for the first time and it doesn't work.

I'm using SASS and have altered the font path in the `_variables.scss` file, tried a few paths. But from what I can see in the network trace, no attempt is made to download the font file.

Moreover, I see this yellow warning symbol for the glyphicon CSS rule.

[image: Screenshot of warning]

On hover, the message is:

> Invalid property value

I'm using a copy-paste of the example code from the Bootstrap docs.

In FireFox, the rule above isn't even listed, I see:

[image: Screenshot of FireFox]

What gives?

Comment: are you missing quotes?

Comment: Maybe your font path is still incorrect...

Comment: It's going to be something stupid, I bet. I just can't work out why there's no 404 anywhere. I'm going to get Fiddler on the case and see fo real. Side-tracked on other things at mo.

Comment: @DanielCheung You were right. Though *I* wasn't missing the quotes, see answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!! Woohoo!!

So the SCSS is wrong. Check it out:

[image: Screen dump of bad SCSS]

The quoted one was my test.

Daniel Cheung was right. It's all missing quotes in the source. I wouldn't have expected it.

Just checked and on GitHub the commit note on that file is:

> Revert "Fix #803 by unquoting all UTF8 escapes"

Ha ha!

Comment: Because I can't. You can't just QA yourself in under 2 days or something.

Comment: To fix, upgrade bootstrap-sass from version `3.3.2` to version `3.3.2+1`